# What is the best way to store user specific files in Wicket?

Tags: file, session, wicket

I am creating a file that is user specific. This file is basically a results csv that is created with the option for the user to download or not. When the user leaves the page, or ends their session I want to be able to delete this file. What is the best way to handle this?

Currently I am using the File class for Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write a file in the first place. Create the content on the fly and stream it back to the client. Wicket has a few classes in the package `org.apache.wicket.request.resource` to help with that.

As a starting point, look at [Wicket 6 resource management](http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-resource-management/) and [Wicket 1.5 Mounting resources](http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/)

You basically mount a resource in the WicketApplication.init():

```
mountResource("somePath/${param1}/${param2}", new SomeResourceReference());
```

Than the SomeResourceReference:

```
public class SomeResourceReference extends ResourceReference {

   @Override
   public IResource getResource() {
      return new SomeResource();
   }

}
```

And finally in SomeResource:

```
 public class SomeResource extends AbstractResource {

     @Override
     public AbstractResource.ResourceResponse 
                   newResourceResponse(Attributes attributes) {

        // get the parameters
        PageParameters parameters = attributes.getParameters();
        final String param1 = parameters.get("param1").toStringObject();

         AbstractResource.ResourceResponse response 
                           = new AbstractResource.ResourceResponse();

         response.setContentType("application/CSV");
         response.setCacheDuration(Duration.NONE);
         response.setCacheScope(WebResponse.CacheScope.PRIVATE);
         response.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.INLINE);

         response.setWriteCallback(new AbstractResource.WriteCallback() {

         @Override
         public void writeData(final Attributes attributes) throws IOException {
            // create your data here 
            attributes.getResponse().write(dataAsString);
         }
        });

    return response;

     }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks Bert!  I will read the references given and see if I can implement this. I will probably be back with some more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Wicket doesn't control destroying the session. It is the concern of the servlet container you are using.

If you want to create a file in Wicket and delete the file when the session is destroyed or user want logout, it has two parts:

1. User logout (in Wikcet)
   Store the file path or the file reference in the WebSession (Wicket) 
   Override the method invalidate() of your WebSession or AutheticatedWebSession, see http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebSession.html#invalidate%28%29
2. Session destroyed
   Store the file path or the file reference into the container session and write your listener and add it to the your servlet context (e.g. tomcat using web.xml file).
   See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html

Comment: Nice, this worked well. I overloaded the onValidate() as suggessted. I am also going to try bert's suggestion. Thanks!